# _UIDelayedPresentationContext beginDelayedPresentation causing crashes on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I have been getting rather strange crash reports from my live app with stack traces like the following:

```
Thread 0: Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x38af7942 realizeClass(objc_class*) + 117
1  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x390dbef5 szone_malloc_should_clear + 1376
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x38af976f lookUpImpOrForward + 74
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x38af1feb _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 34
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x38af1db9 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 24
5  UIKit                          0x30e571bf __57-[_UIDelayedPresentationContext beginDelayedPresentation]_block_invoke + 26
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x38fd9d07 _dispatch_client_callout + 22
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x38fe2803 _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 262
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x38fe073d _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 188
9  CoreFoundation                 0x2e3ef819 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
10 CoreFoundation                 0x2e3ee0ed __CFRunLoopRun + 1300
11 CoreFoundation                 0x2e358c27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
12 CoreFoundation                 0x2e358a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
13 GraphicsServices               0x3302c283 GSEventRunModal + 138
14 UIKit                          0x30bfc049 UIApplicationMain + 1136
```

This is rather mysterious because neither the main thread nor any of the other live threads in the reports seem to imply that this is caused by my code, though of course I am skeptical of this.

This seems to be a rather common crash according to the number of reports I receive from Crashlytics, yet I have not been able to reproduce it on my own devices. I suspect this is probably related to some memory management issues because the various crashes always end up being some bad pointers being sent messages.

This always happens on this thread and following the `-[_UIDelayedPresentationContext beginDelayedPresentation]_block_invoke` call. This is obviously a private class being referenced from within some Apple framework, however I am at a loss to figure out exactly which one could be calling this.

The app is an educational game and I suspect this could be related to the GameKit API (particularly the Game Center authentication dialogs).

All of these crashes have been happening exclusively on **iOS 7** and on **iPad** only. The app is universal so it is interesting to see that iPhone users seem to be unaffected.

Does anybody have any previous experience with these private classes that could give me some hints?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I may be having a similar issue.

Comment: Wow, completely forgot about this 5-year old issue. I'm guessing this got addressed in later versions of iOS.